# SQL Trigger fallback

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, db2

My bosses nor any of the DBAs know how to make triggers and I don't neither(new-ish programmer), they just copied/pasted some old triggers from the DB for examples for me.  Anyway, my triggers copy data from one table to another after an update/insert.  The insert/update that goes to the original table is vital, so if anything fails, I just want the trigger to fail and the original insert/update to still run just fine.

I am using MySQL to test, but we use DB2, but they won't give me access to test triggers in their DB2 environemt, so this the closest solution I can use to test the trigger logic.

I noticed that BEGIN ATOMIC is in the example triggers, does that do what I want?  And what would be equivalent in MySQL, so I can test?

I have subselects in my triggers are these safe? Should I declare variables to help avoid issues?

Comment: maybe you can play around with commit and rollback with triggers if any of them fails just rollback.

Comment: development/testing in MySQL while using DB2 in prod seems like a bad idea.  What platform of DB2?  If Linux/Unix/Windows, then install the free edition of DB2 on your PC.  If IBM i or Z/OS, then you need to have your own schema you can create test tables/triggers in.

Comment: I agree with Charles. Get yourself a Db2 instance to test on. You could use a free cloud account https://www.ibm.com/cloud/db2-on-cloud if you don't want to download and use one of the free developer editions https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-db2-direct-and-developer-editions

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify,, I'm not going to promote the mySQL versions to prod.  1st, I have to get my triggers into our testing region which the testers will use to test all of them.  So, no matter what they'll have to all work with DB2 first.  Looking at MySql install vs DB2 install, I thought MySql was a bit easier to install and play around with.  I mean the only difference I've had to make was adding delimeters, and add more semicolons and take off my begin atomics for plain begin/ends.  I was even able to store same data types in my mock tables that are in are db2 tables.

Comment: That's like testing in Java before deploying in C++, it's close enough, right? (OMG!)

Answer (score 1):

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
create table test_trigger (i int) in userspace1@
create table test_trigger_copy (i int) in userspace1@

create or replace trigger test_trigger_air
after insert on test_trigger
referencing new as n
for each row
begin
  declare continue handler for sqlexception begin end;
  insert into test_trigger_copy(i) values (case when mod (n.i, 2)=0 then cast(RAISE_ERROR('70001', 'No even numbers!') as int) else n.i end);
end@

insert into test_trigger(i) values 1, 2, 3@
select * from test_trigger_copy@
select * from test_trigger@
```

For DB2 (for LUW at least) databases.

The INSERT statement inside the trigger generates an exception when you try to insert an even number into the base table. The CONTINUE handler consumes exceptions, so you get all inserted numbers in the base table, but only odd numbers in the copy table.

Answer (score 0):

A close MySQL equivalent to DB2's BEGIN ATOMIC, would be a combination of `START TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT`,  `EXIT HANDLER`, and `ROLLBACK`. Instead of:

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
<statement(s)>
END
```

one could do the following in MySQL:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    RESIGNAL;
    END;
  START TRANSACTION;
     <statement(s)>
  COMMIT;
END
```

As to subselects (you mean subqueries?) in the trigger, I do not see why they would not work, as long as you observe the [restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html).